# Generic type inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection

```
public class BaseGenericType<T>
{
}

public class SubGenericType<T>: BaseGenericType<List<T>>
{
}
```

I have two generic types above, which one inherits from another but is still generic.
 The strange thing I can't figure out is that `typeof(SubGenericType<>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseGenericType<>))` returns false. And `typeof(SubGenericType<>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseGenericType<List<>>))` still returns false. I've tried `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` and `MakeGenericType()` and `GetGenericArguments()` to check the inheritance, still not working. But `typeof(SubGenericType<int>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseGenericType<List<int>>))` returns true.

What I want is to get all classes by reflection then grab the specific class which inherits from a generic type passed in.

e.g.

> (1)`List<int>` **-->**
>
> (2)get generic type definition **==>** `List<T>` **-->**
>
> (3)make generic **==>** `BaseGenericType<List<T>>` **-->**
>
> (4)find subclass **==>** `SubGenericType<T>`
>
> (5)make generic **==>** `SubGenericType<int>`

In step (4) I find nothing although I actually have that `SubGenericType<T>`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I wrote this method to check generic type inheritance:

```
    static bool IsSubclassOfOpenGeneric(Type generic, Type toCheck)
    {
        while (toCheck != null && toCheck != typeof(object))
        {
            var cur = toCheck.IsGenericType ? toCheck.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : toCheck;
            if (generic == cur)
            {
                return true;
            }
            toCheck = toCheck.BaseType;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This returns true:

```
IsSubclassOfOpenGeneric(typeof(BaseGenericType<>), typeof(SubGenericType<int>))
```

It doesn't check interfaces though.

By the way, usually if you have relations like this, and you write all the classes yourself, **consider using interfaces**. It is much easier to handle. You can for instance have a `IGenericType` interface *without* generic argument. Sometome you just do not care about the generic type and just want to access members which do not depend on the generic type. Sometimes you want to simply check if it *is* one of those. *And* you can use type variance.

Comment: Thanks man! I've solved this using a simple solution. I'll post it later. As you mentioned `interface`, I did have an interface constraint, but what makes the **SubClassFinding** step complex is that the generic parameter is a generic type itself, or even worse: recursive. I'll try your solution, it looks neat. Thanks again.

Comment: `IsSubclassOfOpenGeneric(typeof(BaseGenericType<>), typeof(SubGenericType<>))` It actually works! guess I should've used `type.BaseType` looping for the root type(other than `Object`). :D

Comment: This code incorrectly returns true when both parameters are the same generic class. I have added this line "if (generic == toCheck) return false;" as the first line in the method IsSubclassOfOpenGeneric to make this method to return false when both parameters of the method are the same. The code is tested. It makes the behavior consistent with the .NET Framework method IsSubclassOf. This code returns false: var result = typeof(GenericBaseClass<int, int>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(GenericBaseClass<int, int>); Moderators rejected my edit so if you about to use this code in production add this change.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured it out.
This is the very solution. To explain in details, I have to introduce some non-abstract coding:

It's about a value converter. My purpose is simple, to let users add their own **value converters**. In the conversion step, I will check built-in types' converters first(as `IConvertible`), if not found, I'll first search the current executing assembly for all custom converter classes that inherit a specific `abstract` class provided by me. And an `interface` is implemented by that `abstract` class to make constraint for later reflection. Then I filter those reflected classes for the one that matches.

Here is the base class and interface(all nested):

```cs
    private interface ICustomConverter
    {
        Type SourceType { get; }

        object CallConvert(string input);
    }

    public abstract class CustomConverter<T> : ICustomConverter
    {
        public abstract T Convert(string input);

        public Type SourceType
        {
            get { return typeof (T); }
        }

        object ICustomConverter.CallConvert(string input)
        {
            return Convert(input);
        }
    }
```

I've made the interface private in the parent class and implemented explicitly. So that the method `CallConvert()` won't be called outside.

The **generic parameter** `T` is the Type to convert the `string` value to.
e.g.

```cs
    public class Int32Converter:CustomConverter<int>
    {
    }
```

This is easy to handle since the conversion target type isn't generic. all I need to do is to get all types that implement `ICustomConverter`, and make a generic type from `CustomConverter<T>` with the given `int`, thus `CustomConverter<int>`. Then I filter those classes for the one that derives from `CustomConverter<int>`, and here I found `Int32Converter`.

Later I came across this situation:

```cs
    public class ListConverter<T>:CustomConverter<List<T>>
    {
    }
```

and

```cs
    public class DictConverter<T,U>:CustomConverter<Dictionary<T,U>>
    {
    }
```

I used the same process to deal with them. But after I made a generic type `CustomConverter<List<T>>`, I found that `ListConverter<T>` does not derive from `CustomConverter<List<T>>` and `CustomConverter<List<T>>` is not assignable from
`ListConverter<T>`(which I checked with `IsAssignableFrom()` and `IsSubclassOf()`).

I guess the reason is that generic type stands for more than one type before the generic parameters are assigned.
This sounds weird but it is true. **The compiler doesn't know that the `T` in `CustomConverter<List<T>>` and `ListConverter<T>` stand for the same TYPE**
In fact, I can write it like `CustomConverter<List<T>>` and `ListConverter<U>`, and then you tell me the inheritance relationship between them.

And base type checking won't work here since `ListConverter<T>` and `DictConverter<T,U>` share the same root class. This means if I look for `ListConverter<T>`, I'll get `DictConverter<T,U>` too with the base class checking method(hierarchy loop checking). So I still have to make generic type, then check generic arguments and do type comparing.

**The point is that I need to look for the specific class whose generic parameters are used as the generic arguments in its parent class's generic parameter. Sort of twisted but now it is clear.**

Here is the final **Convertion** solution:

```cs
    public static object ToObject(Type type, string value)
        {
            if (type == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
            if (!typeof (IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                if (type.IsGenericType)
                {
                    Type converterType = typeof (CustomConverter<>).MakeGenericType(type);
                    Type genericConverter =
                        typeof (ICustomConverter).Assembly.Types(Flags.Public)
                            .SingleOrDefault(
                                t =>
                                    typeof (ICustomConverter).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsGenericType &&
                                    t.GetGenericArguments().Length == type.GetGenericArguments().Length && !t.IsAbstract &&
                                    t.MakeGenericType(type.GetGenericArguments()).IsSubclassOf(converterType));
                    if (genericConverter != null)
                    {
                        Type customConverter = genericConverter.MakeGenericType(type.GetGenericArguments());
                        object instance = customConverter.CreateInstance();
                        if (instance is ICustomConverter)
                            return ((ICustomConverter) instance).CallConvert(value);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Type converterType = typeof (CustomConverter<>).MakeGenericType(type);
                    Type customConverter =
                        typeof (ICustomConverter).Assembly.Types(Flags.Public)
                            .SingleOrDefault(t => t.IsSubclassOf(converterType));
                    if (customConverter != null)
                    {
                        object instance = customConverter.CreateInstance();
                        if (instance is ICustomConverter)
                            return ((ICustomConverter) instance).CallConvert(value);
                    }
                }
    
    
                throw new ArgumentException("type is not IConvertible and no custom converters found", type.Name());
            }
            TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
            return converter.ConvertFromString(value);
        }
```

I also checked `GetGenericArguments().Length` in case `List<T>` messes with `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

*Note: some custom extension methods are used.*